# Problem Open Graph tags not working for LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

https://logrhythm.com/

The above webpage has the following Open Graph tags

```
<meta property="og:title" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" content="LogRhythm, The Security Intelligence Company">
<meta property="og:description" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" content="LogRhythm&#39;s security intelligence and analytics platform enables organizations to detect and neutralize cyber threats. Improve your security intelligence.">
<meta property="og:image" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" content="https://logrhythm.com/images/thumbnail.png">
<meta property="og:url" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" content="https://logrhythm.com/">
```

These tags pass the Facebook Debugger

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Flogrhythm.com%2F

as well as other debuggers

http://iframely.com/debug?uri=https%3A%2F%2Flogrhythm.com%2F

---

The problem is LinkedIn does not pick up this data at all. It appears the **scraper** is following a redirect located in a `<noscript>` tag on the site:

```
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/no-script">
</noscript>
```

First and foremost, I'd like it validated that this is infact the reason for the OG tags not getting recognized. Second, is there any way to continue redirecting users with JavaScript disabled, and get OG data into LinkedIn?

---

### Update

After removing the `<noscript>` tag the issue with OG persists. I've even added garbage to the url to combat the caching.

[image]

Comment: You may want to hide this `<noscript>` tag for LinkedIn bot, otherwise, don't expect LinkedIn to improve their bot overnight.

Comment: I can't its a static site